# How long will workflow action "wait for..." actually wait?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

Does anyone have any idea how long the "wait for..." actions in a workflow will actually wait for? I have a use-case where it could be years before someone changes a field and I'm wondering if the workflow would still respond.

I can't find any documentation specifying any limits of this action, but I know completed workflow history will delete after 90 days in our SP Online environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this kind of changes, I recommend you to do

- edit actual workflow to: **end it after going to phase "waiting for..."**
- create new workflow which will be started when the **item is edited**, you can check at start **if was edited the correct field and continue or end** in workflow. *This workflow will continue in flow where the first ended.*

*Its Safer then believe to the functional running WF in few years... Otherwise You should edit actual workflow with the stage changer at start, if you will need restart this WF in future, so it will continue where it ends by WF status.*

Comment: I agree, I don't want to rely on it running for years. We are going to use a separate workflow that starts on edit and check column status. Thanks! I'm going to leave question open to see if anyone knows if Microsoft has an actual documented length of time.

Comment: Ok, we are gold partner for MS, i will try digging more informations about it, but probably they don't know too, cause nobody do that :)